# I want to update only those columns in my database whose textboxes are enabled and keep previous data for those which are disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows

(http://s14.directupload.net/images/140127/fooispgt.jpg) Link for image

Please view image for more clarification of the problem bcz i know i'm not able to make it more clear to you.

I want to update data for only those columns which are checked by user via checkboxes and those which are left unchecked don't get updated by NULL value....

what i'm thinking is use 511 if....else conditions each for different update query but it's not possible to implement this.

till now the code for update is this:

```
else if(update_rdbtn.Checked)
            {

                FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.imglocation_lbl.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
                imgbtarray = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JackSparrow-PC\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HCE_DB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update StudentInfo SET Rollno='" + this.rollno_txtbox.Text + "',Student_Name='" + this.studname_txtbox.Text + "',F_name='" + this.fname_txtbox.Text + "',D_O_B='" + this.dob_txtbox.Text + "',Address='" + this.address_txtbox.Text + "',Phone='" + this.phone_txtbox.Text + "',Valid_upto='" + this.validupto_txtbox.Text + "',Image=@IMG,Branch='" + this.branch_txtbox.Text + "' WHERE Rollno='" + this.rollno_txtbox.Text + "';", con);
                SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", imgbtarray));
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Data has been updated");
                myReader.Close();
                con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Code for radio btn on checked changed:

```
   private void update_rdbtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        update_grpbox.Enabled = true;
        studname_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        fname_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        dob_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        branch_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        address_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        phone_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        validupto_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        Browse_btn.Enabled = false;
        studname_chkbox.Checked = false;
        fname_chkbox.Checked = false;
        dob_chkbox.Checked = false;
        branch_chkbox.Checked = false;
        Address_chkbox.Checked = false;
        phone_chkbox.Checked = false;
        validupto_chkbox.Checked = false;
        Uploadimg_chkbox.Checked = false;
    }
```

Code for check boxes:

```
 private void studname_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!studname_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            studname_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            studname_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void fname_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fname_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            fname_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            fname_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void dob_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dob_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            dob_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dob_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void branch_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!branch_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            branch_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            branch_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Address_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Address_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            address_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            address_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void phone_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!phone_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            phone_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            phone_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void validupto_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!validupto_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            validupto_txtbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            validupto_txtbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Uploadimg_chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Uploadimg_chkbox.Checked)
        {
            Browse_btn.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Browse_btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, i suggest you change, edit in datagrid, no in the form with textbox.

Have a event in datagridview called " CellEndEdit " i think its can solve your problem

Comment: Thanxx @Dietrich to reply but i have solved it using sqlreader by reading the previous data before it gets updated by newest data and store that data into different string type variable and for image i use byte array

Comment: And used if(!sname_chkbox.checked) get data from stored variables....else update data with user input

Comment: I have one more query i.e I have developed a windows app in c#

Having HCE_DB.mdf file with two tables Admin and StudentInfo 

Whenever i click a button to store data in my database then mycommand executes successfully and it says data added successfully  and when i load data to view it in datagridview than also it shows the data which i have added.

But when i closed my app and start it again then all data has been lost....

Plz help me